# Android Kotlin AES Decryption returns Bad Decryption

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, openssl, aes

I currently have a problem with the decryption of my file. The problem is already holding me up for a few days. Every attempt ends in a BAD_DECRYPT exception. This is what the decrypt code looks like.

```
val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
        val spec = PBEKeySpec(Constant().SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), Constant().SALT_KEY.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()), 65536, 256)
        val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
        val secret = SecretKeySpec(tmp.encoded, "AES")
        val ivKeyBytes = Constant().IV_SECRET_KEY.toByteArray()
        val finalIvs = ByteArray(16)
        val len = if (ivKeyBytes.count() > 16) 16 else ivKeyBytes.count()
        System.arraycopy(ivKeyBytes, 0, finalIvs, 0, len)
        val ivps = IvParameterSpec(finalIvs)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivps)
        return cipher.doFinal(fileData)
```

The encryption happens via a task on my server with openssl this looks like this

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in PATH_TO_MY_FILE -out PATH_TO_MY_ENC_FILE -S "MYSALT_IN_HEX" -iv "MY_IV_IN_HEX" -k MY_KEY_PASS
```

What i make wrong? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for `SecretKeyFactory` doesn't seem right. You are using openssl without pbkdf2 flag and with md5 hash. I think the corresponding algorithm would be "PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL" from bouncy castle provider.

You also need to extract cipher text from the file - it starts with Salted__ string, followed by the salt, followed by the cipher text.

With these changes decryption works fine for me:

```
    Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
    val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC")
    val salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileData, 8, 16)
    val spec = PBEKeySpec(Constant().SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256)
    ...
    val ct = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileData, 16, fileData.size)
    return cipher.doFinal(ct)
```

Comment: nope i changed the ```SecretKeyFactory``` algorithm to the ```PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL``` but nothing changed it returns  BAD_DECRYPT

Comment: Thx for you're edit, i get no BAD_DECRYPT Error the only think what didn't work is the data are half decrypted and half normal it's a mix of both :/